# 3 column to 2 column stacked layout w/ Susy (EG twitter)

Tags: css, susy-compass, susy-sass, susy

I've been working with Susy for a while now and came across a use case that I can't seem to figure out.  The best way to explain it is to use Twitter as an example.

If you look on their site you'll see they use a three column standard layout with a break point at 1250.  After that point is reached, the entire right most column 3 goes underneath column 1.

How is this done with pure CSS in Susy 2? When I look at twitter it seems like they are physically moving the content from column 3 into column 1.  I'm assuming this is all done with JS but id rather do it a bit more clean.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was as simple as using breakpoint as another mixin for my columns.  I simply added

```
@import "breakpoint";

@include breakpoint (new screen size here) {
.right span (5 of 13);
.left span (8 of 13 last);
.middle span (5 of 13);
}
```